# java there is no newline after xml decleration

Tags: xml, parsing, dom, w3c, transformer-model

After modifying an `xml` document, I have written this document to a new file. In this `xml` file, however, a line break is missing after the `xml` declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"><!DOCTYPE EMail SYSTEM "../src/email.dtd">
<Mail><Person>John</Person>
<Number>7</Number>
</Mail>

public void createDoc(File outputFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, TransformerConfigurationException,
    TransformerException, TransformerFactoryConfigurationError {

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, this.dtdName);
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(this.doc), new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile))));
}
```

why is there no line break between the xml decl and the doctype tag? if I open the file with Notepad and want to make a line break right now, Notepad crashes. is that a bug of Java?

Comment: reformat your code to make it more readable please.

Comment: what exactly are you asking? what is the expected result?

Comment: @Daniel M: why is there no line break between the xml decl and the doctype tag? if I open the file with Notepad and want to make a line break right now, Notepad crashes. is that a bug of Java?